# Send scheduled email to contact (parent) related to event participant (child)

Tags: relationships, scheduled-reminders, civicrm-event

We are using CiviCRM 5.70.2 on Drupal 10.2.4.

CiviCRM has contacts that are parents and contacts that are children, which have a relationship with each other. Parent contacts have an email. Children contacts do not have an email.

The children are registered for events, parents are not registered for the events.
Some children are registered for multiple events.
Some parents have registered more than on child for an event.

We want to send a scheduled reminder email to the parent 2 weeks before the start date of the event for which the child is registered. I know how to schedule a reminder an email to an event participant. I know how to create a group of contacts (parents) who have a child in a certain event. I can create such a group for each event and then use that group to **manually** send an email to the parent on X days before the child's event begins.

But, how can I schedule an automatic reminder email to the related parent of a child x days before the child's event begins?  The schedule reminder function does not seem to have that option.

Comment: Have you tried using `CiviRule` + `Emailapi` Extension? I think it provides Send email to related contact as an action.

Answer (score 1):

Seems possible using [civirules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) + [emailapi](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) extension -

Trigger: `Event Date reached`; Offset: `2 Week(s) before "Start Date"`

Action: `Send Email to a related contact`

An test rule setup might look like:

[image]